# Need to visit a registration link multiple times in Cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I have a bunch of Cypress tests that are being driven by a fixture file which contains the number of tests I want to run.

As part of my tests. I need to visit a registration link and register a new account.

The problem is that the first time I visit the registration form. It appears fine. But if I go to it again. The new form doesn't show and I only see the regular login form.

I suspect that because I'm running multiple tests from one spec file that Cypress is remembering that I've already visited the page and showing me the log in form.

I know I shouldn't be using the UI to register new accounts. But it's the only solution currently.

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
let user;

before(function () {
    cy.task("newUser").then((user) => {
        user = user;
    });
});

const types = require("../fixtures/types");

types.forEach((type) => {
    context("Matter Creation", () => {
        it("Tests if a Service Agent can create a new matter", () => {
            cy.fixture("data").then((data) => {
                cy.addNewUser({
                    userEmail: user.email,
                    userPassword: user.password,
                });
            });
        });
    });

    context("User Registration", () => {
        it("Tests the registration process from a users perspective", () => {
            cy.userRegistration({
                userEmail: user.email,
                userPassword: user.password,
            });
        });

        it("Tests that users are registered and can sign in", () => {
            cy.verifyRegistration({
                userEmail: user.email,
                userPassword: user.password,
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by moving my `before` state into my `describe` block.

It was reusing old data, instead of using new data for every test.